# How can I get the Agent entity?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How can I spawn the Agent entity? I am very interested in it, but I can’t even find out how to get it. After a quick look at some commands, it doesn’t seem to be available and I can’t seem to find it in the creative inventory either.

Comment: By the way I am playing Bedrock Edition on my Nintendo Switch.

Comment: It's not possible. You need to be a teacher at an institution

Comment: @RayWu that’s... not right

Comment: @Penguin Yes it is

Comment: @RayWu I can have one like in my answer, I'm not a teacher

Answer (score 1):

## Windows 10

Go to the Microsoft Store on Windows 10 and download “Minecraft Code Connection”. Then set it up and follow its directions. Once connected, you will get an agent.

## Other

The agent is not (to my knowledge) available on other versions of Minecraft.